# Rails: Attempting to query created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following action in my controller:

```
  def find_by_registration_date
    @registration_date = params[:registration_date]
    @registrations = Registration.where(:created_at => @registration_date)
  end
```

...were params[:registration_date] is a simple date (no time) like:

```
"registration_date"=>"2014-07-16"
```

...and my created_at date looks like...

```
created_at: "2014-07-16 15:50:52"
```

How can a search based on Y-M-D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its mysql, you can do

```
@registrations = Registration.where("DATE(created_at) = ? ", @registration_date)
```

For other databases, find the equivalent date function

Comment: Boom! You nailed it...thanx Vimsha.